resource not accessible by integration - repository_dispatch failure
I have a workflow that will trigger other repo workflow on completion. My problem is, the following of yaml below, when run on Github Actions, will always cause resource not accessible by integration.
I have tried setting Read and write permissions on my Github on both repos, but it still fails. I am not sure what is the problem as I have followed the usage guide. Help would be greatly appreciated.
dispatch:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Trigger event dispatch
        uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v3
        with:
          repository: your-repo/your-repo.github.io
          event-type: trigger-download


You need to use a Personal Access Token (PAT). See https://github.com/peter-evans/repository-dispatch?tab=readme-ov-file#token for details.

I can't explain how much of a fool I am, to miss the PAT requirement. Thanks alot!

The issue might be due to authentication. Ensure that a personal access token (PAT) with sufficient permissions is used. In your steps, add a GITHUB_TOKEN or PAT with workflow scope for both repositories:
following is yaml file:
with:
token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
Make sure both repositories have workflow permissions enabled for this token under repository settings.
